# How to group ruby array based on id in the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have two models post and topic which has a one to many relation

```
#Post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic
  validates :topic_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

if i have an array of posts by calling `Post.all` for example

```
    #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "Rails Code", body: "class TopicsController < ApplicationController\r\n  ...", created_at: "2018-05-22 09:34:15", updated_at: "2018-05-22 09:34:15", topic_id: "2">, 
#<Post id: 2, title: "Post with tags", body: "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq...", created_at: "2018-05-22 11:48:54", updated_at: "2018-05-22 11:48:54", topic_id: "2">, 
#<Post id: 3, title: "12hello world12", body: "12312sdfsdfsdsdsdsd31231231231231", created_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:02", updated_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:02", topic_id: "2">,
 #<Post id: 4, title: "12hello world12", body: "12312sdfsdfsdsdsdsd31231231231231", created_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:09", updated_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:09", topic_id: "1">,
 #<Post id: 5, title: "12hellsdssdo world12", body: "12312sdfsdfsdsdsdsd31231231231231", created_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:15", updated_at: "2018-05-23 12:54:15", topic_id: "1">]>
```

is there a way i could group them by their `topic_id`  so i could display them topic by topic

example

```
Topic - 1
post 1    post2   post 3
Topic -2
post4   post5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Post.all.group_by(&:topic_id).each do |topic_id, posts|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
You can do it using ruby's [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
post.group_by{|post| post.topic_id}
```

Comment: `post.group_by(&:topic_id)` is more idiomatic.